# Using an if statement with the in operator

Tags: javascript, client-side

```
var srcType = source.slice(source.lastIndexOf('.'));
//srcType = fileExtension
var imageFormats = ['.jpg','.png','.gif'],
videoFormats = ['.ogv','.png','.gif'];
// two lists, acceptable video/image types
var htmlSting = ''; / /initialize the htmlstring

if (srcType in imageFormats) //heres where my question is!!!
    htmlString = '<img class="empty" id="it" src="'+source+'"> </img>';
else
    htmlString = '<video class="empty" id="it" src="'+source+'" controls> </img>';
// these statements choose the proper media type.
```

Ok, so heres the deal: I am coding something that needs to choose html based on a filetype.
is there a way to achieve the (srcType in imageFormats)? This doesn't work. Do I need a for loop? I could always use or's in the html, but that would be exhaustive as we add formats.
Reason I don't like a for loop is that it uses precious time in a time-critical area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'in' operation works only over the properties of an object, not the values of an array.  I think you want indexOf(srcType), which returns -1 if not found, or the index if found.

```
imageFormats.indexOf('.jpg'); // => 0
imageFormats.indexOf('.foo'); // => -1

if(imageFormats.indexOf(srcType)){ }

var obj = {a: 1};
if('a' in obj){ } // evaluates to true
if('b' in obj){ } // evaluates to false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on an Array object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj) for details on options available in javascript libraries.

`indexOf` is available from JavaScript 1.6 (ECMAScript 5th Edition) and there is a fallback for older browsers in the MDC page linked.

> Reason I don't like a for loop is that it uses precious time in a
>   time-critical area.

You will have to give more details. A simple loop will not take much time, and all you have is a set of three elements in the array. Even with the potential of this becoming 50 or 100, the for loop should not be much of a problem.

Also, If you can give the intention of what you are doing (and when), you might get better answers.

Comment: Thank you for helping. The reason I don't want to use for is b/c it has to run the process hundreds of times and would get laggy.
Matt answered with what I needed :)